# Use timedelta() with Django's models.DateField

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to compute the expiration date of a service provided in my `Django 1.5` project

I imported: `from datetime import datetime, date` in the `model.py` file and wrote the function as it follows:

```
def expirationdate(self):
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.today(),'%Y-%m-%d')
        return date + datetime.timedelta(days=self.premiumduration)
```

where self.premiumduration is defined in my module like this:

```
premiumduration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

this function is called by an `HTML` template but it raise the following error:

**AttributeError at /user/Adriano/**

**type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/Adriano/

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'app_is')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Adriano\Desktop\site_is\app_is\templates\user.html, error at line 31
   type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
   21 :         {% endif %}


   22 :         {% if view_user_profile.card_type == '' %}


   23 :             <p>Card type: Not Saved


   24 :             <p>Card Number: Not Saved


   25 :         {% else %}


   26 :             <p>Card type: {{ view_user_profile.get_card_type_display }}


   27 :             <p>Card Number: {{ view_user_profile.cardinfo }}


   28 :         {% endif %}


   29 :         {% if view_user_profile.premiumstatus %}


   30 :             <p>You are a premium user from {{view_user_profile.premiumactivation}}</p>


   31 :             <p>Your premium subscription will expire  {{ view_user_profile.expirationdate }} </p>


   32 :         {% else %}


   33 :             <p>You are not a premium user yet! Buy your premium account <a href="/premium/">here!</p>


   34 :         {% endif %}


   35 :     {% endif %}


   36 : 


   37 :     


   38 :     {% if view_user == request.user %}


   39 :     <form action="/modify/" method="get">


   40 :         <input id="submit" type="button" value="Modify your profile" />


   41 :     </form>


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adriano\Desktop\site_is\app_is\views.py" in userpage
  148.  return render(request, 'user.html', {'request': request, 'view_user': view_user, 'view_user_profile': view_user_profile})
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  177.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  63.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  284.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  284.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render
  84.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  578.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  728.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  779.                             current = current()
File "C:\Users\Adriano\Desktop\site_is\app_is\models.py" in expirationdate
  48.       date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.premiumactivation,'%Y-%m-%d')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /user/Adriano/
Exception Value: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the combination of:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(...)
```

You're importing the *class* `datetime` from the `datetime` *module*.  `strptime` is a method on the `datetime` *class*, so you could fix the first error if you just use:

```
datetime.strptime(...)
```

But, then you'll get an error about `datetime.timedelta`<sup>1</sup>.  I think what you *actually* want is to change the import statement:

```
import datetime
```

Now the `datetime` *class* is accessed by `datetime.datetime` as you did in your original code and `timedelta` is accessed by `datetime.timedelta` (again, the same as your original code).   Of course, you will need to change `date` to `datetime.date` unless you import it separately (which I don't recommend).

<sup><sup>1</sup>I like to think of this as programming "Whack-a-mole"</sup>

Comment: Ok, now run without errors, unfortunately it doesn't show any value on my web page. Anyhow, thaks!

Comment: Good luck with that.  I'm not a django guy so I probably won't be much help there.